# Encoding issues, basic Apache and PHP, after distro upgrade of Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I distro upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 on my Linode ([www.linode.com](http://www.linode.com)), as per instructions on https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-22-04/ .

It worked. It's up and running. But I have a couple of issues. One is that http://powershellhelp.space is rendering as plain text instead of interpreted PHP/HTML. However, the other virtual hosts (vhosts in Apache) on the same server are rendering correctly..

In addition, I see double-encoded UTF-8 on the main website (https://www.powershelladmin.com ) with my Norwegian characters. Such as: https://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Finance.php (some are double-encoded UTF-8).

I already tried setting AddDefaultCharset utf-8 and to restart apache.

I set it in both the apache2.conf and charset.conf in a subdirectory of /etc/apache2. If I encode my files as ASCII when creating them, they are rendered with question marks instead of two bytes/characters per each "æøå" character, but not right either way. The Norwegian vowels. It's disturbing how this is still a problem...

Does anyone have suggestions on what to try?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was running:

```
root@localhost:~# a2enmod php8.1
```

And then the websites other than powershelladmin.com loaded correctly. The encoding issue was also seemingly resolved! (Not sure why, have the AddDefaultCharset utf-8 in my Apache config still, FYI).